# How does the DNS seizure process technically work?

Tags: dns

In light of the seizure of Backpage.com.

How does the process of DNS seizure process technically work? Is there a change in the A Record of the DNS to redirect to the seizure IP notification site?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as interesting as the topic is, it's not about programming. I imagine that https://ServerFault.com/ is most likely the StackExchange site that can provide the best help.

Answer (score 1):

According to this (non-authoritative) webpage: https://comptutor.me/2015/05/25/prevent-domain-seizures/

- The government agency finds the registrar responsible for the domain (GoDaddy, NameCheap, etc). The registrar must be under the jurisdiction of the agency and the court that determined the name must be seized.
- Agency gets a court-order that shows they have the right to control the domain-name.
- Agency contacts the registrar, referencing the court-order.
- The registrar authenticates the court-order (hopefully!) and then moves their internal registration to a different customer account representing the agency.
- If the registrar was also hosting the DNS zone, then the zone may or may not be copied over - but more than likely they won't, so they'll just change the domain's SOA (Start of Authority) record to point to DNS zone servers that are under the control of the agency (or self-hosted by the registrar themselves).

So no A records are updated directly - though that is an option if the registrar is hosting the zone, it's far more straightforward just to treat it like any other (voluntary) domain-transfer between two customers of the same registrar.

The court-order may also order the domain name be transferred to another registrar, though as that takes more time it may make sense to do an internal transfer.

Comment: The agency could also pressure directly the registry. As for the juridiction issue there are sometimes cross countries cooperation on that. Have a look at this article: https://labs.ripe.net/Members/stephane_bortzmeyer/dns-censorship-dns-lies-seen-by-atlas-probes for a lot of useful information. You will see that sometimes ISPs are pressured to rewrite DNS traffic to make some domains become unavailable.